# how to display json data from db to table format

Tags: php, html

iam unable to display json data to table format like below

[image]

[image]

```
<?php
    $testData = json_decode($data['test_data'], true);
            $testList = $testData['list'];
    
            $td = array();
            foreach ($testList as $i => $data) {
                if ($i != 0 && $i % 2 == 0) {
                    $td[] = '<td> ' . implode('</td><td></td><td>', $tdata) . '</td><td></td>';
                    $tdata = array();
                }
                $tdata[] = $data['issue_name'];
            }
            echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="10"><tr>' . implode('</tr><tr>', $td) . '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: Why are you "unable" to?  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: @David, code added.

Comment: And in what way does that code not work as expected?  Are you getting an error?  An unexpected result?  Something else?

Comment: yes , not work as expected, for ex count is 15, but display only 14.

Comment: Be specific.  When you debug, what is the runtime value of `$data['test_data']`?  What is the runtime value of `$testList`?  What is the exact HTML output to the page source?  Please debug your code to indicate the specific observed results and indicate what results you expected and why.  "It doesn't work" tells us nothing about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some JSON to SQL converter?

Here is one online: https://www.convertjson.com/json-to-sql.htm

Edit:

I understand now that you want HTML tables, if it's only a one time thing you could use https://www.convertjson.com/json-to-html-table.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a third party npm module available here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-table-converter